# ASP.NET Solution Deployment to Development Server uses Local Paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Using Visual Studio 2010, I deployed my ASP.NET project to a development server and changed the Web.Config to reflect the development server paths. Some of the code is working, but for paths like images and other files, it seems to be looking at the local path of my machine. I looked all around the code for a hint at where it's using my local path, but I replaced all of them and it's still not working.

The DLLs are all compiled in the correct place, everything is up to date, etc. No problems running the code locally, either. Is there a specific step to ensure the deployment that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Error:

```
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   FieldControl(String FieldType, String Argument, Field ParentField) in D:\Users\mydirectory\FieldControl.cs:132
   <more of these>
```

Comment: Post some code samples or something.

Comment: which type of error are you getting??

Comment: Deploy it on local computer but change the location. It might help to reproduce same issues you are having on remote, it  will be easy to track them down and fix.

Answer (score 1):

you adjust your paths with  relative path.

A path relative to the root of the site, determined according to the site root (not the application). Paths relative to the root of the site are useful if you keep application resources cross, such as images or client script files in a folder under the root of the website.

his example assumes that path Assemblies folder is located under the Web site root.

```
"/Assemblies/test.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of an error is not saying that it is looking for that local path, thats just where the error is in the code, the compiler is showing you where the issue is: line 132 of that file.  Check there and you should see what is triggering the NULL ref.

Comment: I've been looking there but still don't understand why that's happening on the dev server and not on my local machine. It says it's looking for 'D:\Users\mydirectory\FieldControl.cs:132' which is my local box, not the directory on the web server where it's running

Comment: Its not looking for that path, its firing an error at that location.
What is line 132 of that file?

Comment: The error knows the name/path of the file from where the code was built, your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. My Web.Config was read only so when I changed the path's on the development server it didn't save correctly. Went back in and changed the path's, then made it read only. Thanks for everyone's help.